# show specific data when i click show button

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem on how to display specific details only. let say for example i have two table salessumarry and rsales and have this ff data for its table.

data from rsales

```
id | name | last_name | age | salessumarry_id |
1  |gejel | rosenthal | 21  |        5        |
```

data from salessumarry (note: this data is from database display to my webpage)

```
id | or_no | sold_by | detail |
5  | 12456 |  fabbie | show   |
6  | 22222 |  nedy   | show   |
```

my problem is this. when i click "show" from my webpage it must select data from rsales where salessumarry_id = salessumarry.id. let say for example i click show for id 5 the expected output must be something like this

```
id | or_no | sold_by | detail |
5  | 12456 |  fabbie | show   |
id | name | last_name | age | salessumarry_id |
1  |gejel | rosenthal | 21  |        5        |
6  | 22222 |  nedy   | show   |
```

i put this in my "show" button but my idea is up to only this point. i don't have idea how to display details when i click show

```
echo '<td style="border-color:#000000; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;"><div align="center"><a  href=displaydetail.php?id=' . $row['id'] .'>show</a></div></td>';
```

Comment: what does the code for displaydetail.php look like ?

Comment: i haven't try, that's  only my idea to get the id but don't know yet how to display details. like what i have shown as expected ouput.

Comment: in a nutshell: your  displaydetail.php takes the id as get parameter which you then process using $_GET array and pass the value to your query which will then filter the results based on the value for the id passed. Let me know if that makes sense. Its not that hard to implement but you'd need to learn a bit more about $_GET/filter query and then create a solution.

Comment: yeah that's why i need atleast a short code example on how to display what i have shown in my expected output.

Comment: do you have a working mysql query here ? can you update your question with that and possibly what should be the desired output ?

Comment: i have show already what is my expected output it's on the 3rd example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic way to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
displaydetail.php
<?php
    // get salessumarry_id  from the URL
    $salessumarry_id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM rsales WHERE salessumarry_id = '$salessumarry_id'";

    // use mysqli/pdo here to to execute the query 
    // and fetch the results into $results array and display it here:
    echo "id | name | last_name | age | salessumarry_id |<br>";
    echo $results['id']. " | ". $results['name']." | ".$results['last_name']." | ";
    echo $results['age']." | ".$results['salessumarry_id']." | ";
?>
```

Hope this helps. This can be further improved but first you need to make sure that 
this part is working.